# how to install Seismic Analysis Code?

Tags: software-installation

I am a new Ubuntu user. Please help me to install [Seismic Analysis Code](https://seiscode.iris.washington.edu/projects/sac) (SAC) on Ubuntu 14.04. I get the following errors after installation:

```
bash: export: `1': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `1': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `0': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Errors from what? What command did you run? What is SAC?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/587054/how-to-install-seismic-analysis-code

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this step:

1. open terminal
2. change directory to `sac-101.6a-linux_x86_64.tar.gz`
3. `sudo tar -zxvf sac-101.6a-linux_x86_64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/`
4. open readme
5. `gedit ~/.bashrc`
6. after that scroll until the end, then copy this script:

   ```sh
   export SACHOME=/usr/local/sac
   source /usr/local/sac/bin/sacinit.sh
   export PATH="/usr/local/sac/bin:$PATH"
   ```
7. finally, open back terminal and type:

   ```sh
   . ~/.bashrc
   ```